# Example of a non-splitting exact sequence $1 \to K \to G \to H \to 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence, infinite-groups

Suppose $G$, $K$ and $H$ are finitely generated infinite groups such that
$$1 \to K \to G \to H \to 1$$ is a short exact sequence.

**Question**: Are there examples where this sequence does not split?

There are examples of such groups when $H$ is finite([Does every short exact sequence split?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3166321/976076))  or when $G$ is not a finitely generated group ([Example of a non-splitting exact sequence $0 → M → M\oplus N → N → 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1082283/976076)).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $1 \to \mathbb Z \times C_2 \to \mathbb Z^2 \times C_4 \to \mathbb Z \times C_2 \to 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$0 \to \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0$

using maps $(x,y) \mapsto (x,2y)$ and $(x,y) \to (x,y\text{ mod }2)$.

The only morphism from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial, so you cannot split.

In more detail: Say $f(x,y) = (x,y\text{ mod }2)$ is our map from $\mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. Now $\mathbb{Z}^2$ doesn't have any elements of order 2, so to have a morphism $g:\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}^2$, you are forced to send $g(0,1)$ to $(0,0)$. Thus $g \circ f$ cannot be the identity. [There's no split.]

Comment: $\mathbb Z_2$ is not infinite.

Comment: To be fair, they ask for all three groups to be infinite.  To fix that, you can just add an  extra factor of $\mathbb{Z}$ to each group, and define the maps to be the identity on those components.

Comment: I guess I didn't read the question very carefully. :P

Comment: Thank you, I don't think $Im(f) = ker(g)$ in this case?

Comment: The first group should be $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Ok. Now this is fixed. I had accidentally flipped my factors around (but not consistently).